# wood sander : sheet cannot hold in

Tags: wood, tools, powertools

I have this wood polisher a Bosch PSS240A. Issue is the the polishing sheet cannot stick at the front, even after locking it.

[image]

Each time I'm starting to polish wood, the sheet is ok as you can see

[image]

But after a few seconds of polishing , the sheet is out as the clipping cannot hold the sheet

[image]

How come? Is there anything I can do to fix it quickly without needing to go to a repairshop?

Thanks

Comment: The English name for that tool is a  _sander_. I don't know enough about that model to do more than suggest clipping an additional scrap of sandpaper to give it a thicker end to grip.

Comment: Hi @keshlam thanks for your feedback. I went to a repairshop and they said it was due to a broken coil spring. They gave me one address, saying it is the best around for this kind of tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to a repairshop , they said it was due to a broken coil spring.

Quite cheap to fix rather than buying a new wood sander